# Bivariate normal distribution of points

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

I would like to generate points (x,y) in a 2-D plane that has a circular normal distribution similar to this:[image]

I found multiple terms for describing a "circular normal distribution" and yet, I'm not sure which one to use (let me know if bivariate normal distribution is the correct term to use). This explains why I'm having trouble finding an answer to my question.

For example, how would I generate a point (x,y) that has a 30% probability to be inside a circle of $$x^2+y^2 = 2^2$$ using the bivariate normal distribution (if this is the correct theory to use)?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Bivariate normal" includes not only distributions with circular symmetry, but also some distributions for which level sets of the density function are ellipses.

The usual definition is that the pair $(X,Y)$ has a bivariate normal distribution if for every pair of constants $a,b$ (and "constant" in this case means not random) the linear combination $aX+bY$ has a univariate normal distribution.  In fact, in addition to circles and ellipses mentioned above, there are bivariate normal distributions concentrated on a line: e.g. $(X,3X)$.

Now suppose $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables distributed as $N(0,\sigma^2)$.  The joint density is
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/(2\sigma^2)}.
$$
Notice that this is
$$
\frac 1 {2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2\sigma^2)}.
$$
This depends on $x$ and $y$ only through $x^2+y^2$, so the curves of constant density are circles.  Rotating the plane about $(0,0)$ does not change the distribution.  So if you can generate independent normals, you've got it.

Next you raise the question: how to choose the value of $\sigma$ so that $\Pr(X^2+Y^2\le 2^2) = 0.3$.  We have
$$
\Pr(X^2+Y^2 \le 2^2) = \Pr\left( \left(\frac X\sigma\right)^2 + \left(\frac Y \sigma\right)^2 \le \frac {2^2}{\sigma^2} \right) = \Pr\left( Z_1^2+Z_2^2 \le \frac 4 {\sigma^2} \right) \tag 1
$$
where $Z_1,Z_2\sim\mathrm{i.i.d.}\, N(0,1)$.

(BTW, note the way in which I am carefully distinguishing between capital $X$ and lower-case $X$ and between $Y$ and $y$.  I mention this because your question follows other conventions.)

This is greatly simplified by a fact you may find surprising if you haven't thought about this before: $Z_1^2+Z_2^2$ has an *exponential* distribution.  Since $\operatorname{E}(Z_i^2)=1$, it has expected value $2$.  In other words,
$$
\Pr(Z_1^2+Z_2^2 > w) = e^{-w/2} \text{ for } w\ge 0.
$$
$$
\Pr\left( Z_1^2+Z_2^2 > \frac 4 {\sigma^2} \right) = e^{-2/\sigma^2}.
$$
So set that equal to $0.7$ and solve for $\sigma$.

Comment: I don't understand why the exponential in the join density $f(x,y)$ is divided by $\sigma$. I've seen similar formula but without the $\sigma$, this confuse me. I also don't understand why $E(Z_i^2) = 1$ and everything regarding what follows after

Comment: @m_power : I have now labeled one set of displayed equalities "$(1)$".  That is the one that explains why the $\sigma^2$ in the denominator is there.  Since $\operatorname{E}(Z_1)=0$, we have $\operatorname{var}(Z_1) = \operatorname{E}(Z_1^2)$, so that is how I concluded that that is $1$.  As for _why_ that sum of squares has an exponential distribution, a bit of work in polar coordinates can show that.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok. But why is it not $\frac 1 {2\pi\sigma} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2\sigma^2)}$ instead of $\frac 1 {2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2\sigma^2)}$?

Comment: @m_power : That's a density function for the normal distribution.  Notice I asserted that something has a certain exponential distribution.  The expression I wrote involving $\sigma$ came from that, not from the normal density.  I didn't actually prove that the exponential distribution is it.  I think that's been asked and answer here before. If necessary, I can say something about that.  The short answer to that is: polar coordinates. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok because I found in [link](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~jsta/issues/11(4)/JSTA11(4)p5.pdf) that the probability density function is $\frac 1 {2\pi\sigma} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2\sigma^2)}$. I'm just trying to figure out the theory behind the problem that I stated, there is still alot that I need to learn.

Comment: In polar coordinates $\dfrac 1 {2\pi\sigma} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2\sigma^2)} \,dx\,dy$ becomes $\dfrac 1 {2\pi\sigma} e^{-r^2/(2\sigma^2)} r \, dr \, d\theta$ $= \left(\dfrac 1 {2\pi}\,d\theta\right)\left( \dfrac 1 \sigma e^{-r^2/(2\sigma^2)} r\,dr \right)$.  Writing $u = r^2/2$ and hence $du = r\,dr$, the second factor becomes an exponential distribution. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Good, but you see, the $/\sigma$ appears in your equation, but not in your initial answer. It's quite confusing.